# Does a VPN Provider Know My MAC Address?

Tags: vpn, mac-address

I know MAC is a layer 2 address, so it's only sent to the next router in the chain.

Does a VPN provider get that information when I'm connected to their service? Is their router considered the next router or is my actual physical router next in chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not. Tunnel interfaces don't have media addresses assigned to them. In any case the address assigned to another interface, such as a virtual bridge for virtual machines, would different from your network card.